# how to get message from thread to main activity

Tags: android, flutter

i am working on flutter with android as native i am using event channel to listen to stream of events when they are available i am using thread to pass events notification to mainactivity and then from main activity to flutter everything is working fine the only issue i am facing is how to pass message to eventchannel events success
Below given is my code

```
event_channel.setStreamHandler(new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "onListen: ");
               // SipNotifications sip=new SipNotifications();
                //new Thread(sip).start();
                //events.success();
                SipEvents sip=new SipEvents();
                new Thread(sip).start();
              
                //HERE i want msgs from evenhandler so that i can do
                events.success(msg); 

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(Object arguments) {

            }
        });
```

Below Given is my Event Handler

```
        public static Handler eventHandler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        try {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, msg.getData().toString());//Here i am getting messages which is working fine
            //instance.msgs=msg.getData().toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("HANDLER ERROR", "handleMessage: ");
        }
    }
};
```

and Here is my Thread

```
public class SipEvents implements Runnable {
    String eventsNotifications;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!terminateNotifThread) {
                try {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(4);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Log Thread Error");
                    }

                    if (mysipclient != null) {
                        eventsNotifications = mysipclient.GetNotificationsSync();
                        if (eventsNotifications != null && eventsNotifications.length() > 0) {
                            Message messageToMainThread = new Message();
                            Bundle messageData = new Bundle();
                            messageToMainThread.what = 0;
                            messageData.putString("notifmessages", eventsNotifications);
                            messageToMainThread.setData(messageData);
                            eventHandler.sendMessage(messageToMainThread);
                        }
                    }
                    if ((eventsNotifications == null || eventsNotifications.length() < 1) && !terminateNotifThread) {
                        //some error occured. sleep a bit just to be sure to avoid busy loop
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1);
                    }
                    continue;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                if (!terminateNotifThread) {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
                }
            }//here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "main try error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to call `events.success(msg);` inside `handleMessage` method - that is every time `sendMessage` is called from a background thread and `handleMessage` handles that message you should notify event channel

Comment: how should i do tha